# Change opacity based on another column in stacked bar, plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'user_type': ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
    'cluster_phase1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'group': ['Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test'],
    'phase': ['phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2', 'phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2'],
    'col': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'value': [38.0, 62.0, 54.0, 46.0, 37.0, 63.0, 41.0, 59.0],
    'counts': [18, 18, 13, 13, 94, 94, 89, 89]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

user_type cluster_phase1    group   phase  col  value  counts
0         L              A  Control  phase1    0   38.0      18
1         L              A  Control  phase1    1   62.0      18
2         L              A  Control  phase2    0   54.0      13
3         L              A  Control  phase2    1   46.0      13
4         L              A     Test  phase1    0   37.0      94
5         L              A     Test  phase1    1   63.0      94
6         L              A     Test  phase2    0   41.0      89
7         L              A     Test  phase2    1   59.0      89
```

I am creating the following stacked bar plot, using plotly express

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x='cluster_phase1', y='value', color='col',
             facet_row='group', facet_col='phase',
             text='value', title='L')
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

I would like the bars that have `counts < 20` to be more grey, or have a smaller opacity,
in this case the top 2 bars.

I have tried adding

```
for i, count in enumerate(df['counts']):
    opacity = 0.2 if count < 20 else 1.0
    fig.update_traces(opacity=opacity, selector=f"x[{i + 1}]")
```

But it doesnt work.
Any ideas how I could achieve that ?

**UPDATED DATA TO TEST**

```
data1 = {
    'user_type': ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
    'cluster_phase1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'group': ['Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test'],
    'phase': ['phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2', 'phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2'],
    'col': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'value': [38.0, 62.0, 54.0, 46.0, 37.0, 63.0, 41.0, 59.0],
    'counts': [18, 18, 13, 13, 94, 94, 89, 89]
}

data2 = {
    'user_type': ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
    'cluster_phase1': ['B', 'B','B','B','B','B','B','B',],
    'group': ['Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test'],
    'phase': ['phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2', 'phase1', 'phase1', 'phase2', 'phase2'],
    'col': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'value': [38.0, 62.0, 54.0, 46.0, 37.0, 63.0, 41.0, 59.0],
    'counts': [40, 40, 13, 13, 94, 94, 13, 13]
}

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data1), pd.DataFrame(data2)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the [`selector`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.update_traces) :

> [...] If a string `S`, the selector is equivalent to `dict(type=S)`

(... because the string `f"x[{i + 1}]"` won't match any trace)

One way to achieve this is to add the counts as [`custom_data`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar#:%7E:text=custom_data%20,(lasso%20selection%20etc.)) and then use a function as selector for updating only those traces that have a count below the threshold :

```py
fig = px.bar(df, x='cluster_phase1', y='value', color='col',
             facet_row='group', facet_col='phase',
             text='value', title='L', 
             custom_data=['counts'])

fig.update_traces(opacity=0.2, selector=lambda trace: trace['customdata'][0][0] < 20)
```

[image: output]

As you noticed in the comments, this method applies the opacity to the *trace*, which can be a problem if you have more than one stacked bar per subplot and need to distinguish between different markers within the same trace. In this case, see option 2 below.

---

**Option 2 - Apply opacity via `trace.marker.color`**

NB. Because `df['col']` is used to *categorize* data, you might want to convert it as a string, see [Discrete Color with Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#discrete-color-with-plotly-express) :

> Most Plotly Express functions accept a color argument which
> automatically assigns data values to discrete colors if the data is
> non-numeric. If the data is numeric, the color will automatically be
> considered continuous.

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)
```

By doing this, each `trace.marker.color` is an actual (hex) color so we can convert it to rgb(a) and use the alpha channel to set the opacity (with numerical data, `trace.marker.color` would only contain numbers from `col` mapped to a continuous colorscale, so you won't be able to change the opacity that way, ie. if `df['col']` is meant to contain *any* numbers and thus if `df['col']` has to be numeric, you would need a third option) :

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), pd.DataFrame(data2)])
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)

fig = px.bar(df, x='cluster_phase1', y='value', color='col',
             facet_row='group', facet_col='phase',
             text='value', title='L', 
             custom_data=['counts'])

def set_opacity(trace):
    counts = trace.customdata
    r, g, b = plotly.colors.hex_to_rgb(trace.marker.color)
    trace.marker.color = [
        f'rgba({r}, {g}, {b}, {a})'
        for a in map(lambda c: 0.2 if c[0] < 20 else 1.0, counts)]

fig.for_each_trace(set_opacity)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This works in this example, but if you have more than one stacked bar plot at each facet_row+facet_col combination and only one needs to be faded (and not all of them), it does not. Please see "updated data to test" at my edited question to see what I mean